# Model for a random sheet (inspired from the washing machine)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, random-walk, percolation

A friend of mine recently asked me if there was a reason why, when he put a bed sheet in his washing machine, it seemed like the an abnormal proportion of the content of the machine ended up wrapped inside the bed sheet (even if the bed sheet was separately put inside it).

Now I'm not actually sure this is a accurate statement (and I don't actually care so much), but my first instinct was to try to think of it as a statement on percolation clusters. However these clusters are very much non-homeomorphic to the plane. Hence it made me wonder:

**Question:** is there any literature on "random sheets", i.e. a random map from the plane to space which is (say) Lipschitz?

Ideally the image should be non-self-intersecting, but that sounds already too complicated.
As a side note, looking at a random field on (a lattice of) the plane is not fitting here, since there are conditions which are induces by loops, and not just by distance. Furthermore, if one maps the whole plane, one would expect the image to be unbounded (and this is not quite the case in random fields).

Comment: Key phrase: "crumpling transition"

Comment: @user619894 very nice, i'll try to look into it. Do you have any introductory text on this?

Comment: It had it's vogue in the 90's I believe. Physics of Membranes etc, There was a nice review by David Nelson: D.R. Nelson. 1989. “The statistical mechanics of membranes and interfaces.” In Statistical Mechanics of Membranes and Surfaces, 2nd ed., Pp. 1-17. World Scientific.

Comment: link to several references: https://jfi.uchicago.edu/~tten/Crumpling/

Comment: @user619894 Strange that it does not seem that there are many papers in math journals on this...

Comment: Maybe the terminology is different.